# How do i web scrape data using Jsoup

Tags: java, web-scraping

I am creating an app and on it I am web scraping this site https://www.bbc.co.uk/search?q=handsworth I am wondering how I would web scrape the image, heading and description from it as the code below I am able to get the title of the page.

```
StringBuilder newsContent = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    Document page = Jsoup.connect("https://www.bbc.co.uk/search?q=handsworth").get();
                    String title = page.title();

                    newsContent.append(title).append("\n");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    newsContent.append("Error: ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. DOM in https://www.bbc.co.uk/search?q=handsworth is generated by javascript on the fly. Jsoup does not execute javascript.

What you could do is to use real browser for scraping, eg using Selenium